# Module ImportError in running Python Script in JMeter

Tags: python, jmeter, performance-testing

I would like to use python scripts in Jmeter, so I can check the Load and the performance of an application...for that I've created a Thread with JSR223 Sampler, and  I put the content of python script, and after the run, Jmeter throws error like : File "", line 8, in 
ImportError: No module named opcua, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil'
see snapshot: [image]
I don't know how to install this modules (package)in Jmeter, with PyCharm, I installed the package in the Project Interpreter under the setting see the snapshot...[image]

Comment: don't use images, describe your problem in text

Comment: @Ivan..is already described above...the images is to visualize the description

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

1. [Install required module(s)](http://www.jython.org/archive/22/installation.html#can-t-access-standard-python-modules)

   ```
   jython -m pip install foo
   ```
2. Add the next line(s) to the beginning of your script:

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.append('\\location\\of\\jython\\site-packages')
   ```

However from performance perspective it will be much better to re-write your script in [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) as calling Jython interpreter is not the best choice when it comes to high loads.

Also be aware that you can invoke Python interpreter as "external" process using JMeter's [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) (if amount of the existing Python code is too big or too complex to rewrite in Groovy), see [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) for more details.